# Count number of values within a field that accepts unlimited values

Tags: views, entities

I have an image field which can contain unlimited values. How can I display the number of image values contained within this field in views?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first  install [computed field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module then you should write a for loop within variable which count the value of the field then you just output this variable.

Comment: Thx for pointing me to the computed field module. I didn't need to write a loop though. I used count. 
Computed Code:
$entity_field[0]['value'] = count(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_images'));
Display Code:
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
After I made this field, I could diplay i'ts value in views.

Answer (score 11):

There is a way of doing this natively in Drupal 7.

1. Set 'Use aggregation' to Yes
2. Add a field that contains multiple values, such as a file field
3. Set the aggregation settings for it to COUNT DISTINCT

Simple. This will however enable aggregation for all fields, but the default settings for other fields will make them behave normally.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  There might be a better or built in way to do this, but if not, first check the `group multiple values together` configuration option in the field you are dealing with and then create a template for that view and field in question:

```
<?php
$foo=node_load($row->nid);
if (count($foo->field_photo)) {
  print 'There are ' . count($foo->field_photo) . ' photos in this node.';
}
```

By quickly throwing a view together named `foo` with a `field_photo` in it, this would be in a template called `views-view-field--foo--field-photo-fid.tpl.php`

Comment: Excellent! No additional module required here! I put your snippet in `views-view-fields--MYVIEWNAME.tpl.php`

Answer (score 1):

Using Views, you want your view to show fields, and your view field will be the delta of the entity field.

'Delta' just means count.

So for instance on my site in the views 'add field' dialog, I see a field called 'Content: File attachments (upload:delta).' Adding this lets me show how many files have been attached to that node.

When you configure this field, you'll probably want to pay attention to the 'no results behavior' section, to hide it if delta = 0 or something.

HTH.

Comment: is this field the total of all files attached to the node? if so, this works only if he doesn't have any other file fields, right?

Comment: This view field would the total of all files attached at that field. So you could have other file fields and they wouldn't show. But the question is: how do you show the number of files for one attached file field.

Comment: the reason I asked is that in drupal 6 at least, the delta field shows the delta of the individual field, eg, if it has 5 files, it would show 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, one each per row, and not 5, as in the count of them all.  so my question is really in drupal 7 is there another delta field that has the count of all of the content in a field, or is there a field that shows how many files are attached to the node as a whole.

Comment: @Jimajamma you're rigth delta gives oud the position within the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Views PHP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) I added the Photos/Images field as normal and then added a Global PHP field and added:

```
$photos = $data->field_field_images;
$count = count($photos);
//dsm($count);
print $count;
```