# In views, Drupal 7, is there a way to display the total number of fields being displayed from one node?

Tags: views

I have one view outputting images with specific taxonomy term. These are all coming from different nodes. The image field is set to have unlimited values. Some nodes might have 2 images, some 3, you get the point. So what you have is one view displaying possibly 40 or so images. What I would like to output through views is 1 of 3, 2 of 3, etc. as text along with each image.

I already have the current image count using the :delta field, but what I'm missing is the total count.

So there may be 40 images on this page (they're in a slideshow) but I need the count based on the nodes the images are coming from, not the total being displayed by views. Hope this makes sense.

EDIT: Please let me clarify that I also am only trying to display the count of a specific field (image), not from all the fields (title, body, etc) that may be displaying.

---

I found the answer in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28170/count-number-of-values-within-a-field-that-accepts-unlimited-values)

It's the top answer using the computed field module and the code in the comments. It didn't work for me at first so I abandoned it and asked this question. Eventually I went back to it and realized my issue. I had to re-save my node after I added the computed field to my content type. Without doing that it wouldn't display anything.